# get closest tag after insertNode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a wysiwyg where the user can inject text at any position by using some external buttons.

I have a contentEditable div with as an example the following content
 `"<div>123<span>123</span>4567890</div>"`

I use the following code to surround the caret with a span element

```
    var t = document.createElement("span");
    t.textContent = "myElement";
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(t);
```

the output will be for example

`"<div>123<span>123</span>4567<span>myElement</span>890</div>"`

how can I get the node I have injected ?

If i use `injectedElement = window.getSelection().anchorNode` I obtain the full content of the div. I am interested only in `<span>myElement</span>`

Comment: Put random ID to your element, than get element by ID

Comment: By doing it I obtain a string. how can I convert it into a node?

Comment: I mean, you already have a reference to the inserted element. It's `t`. You can store that wherever you want after you insert it.

Comment: can you please explain ? I can do t.setAttribute("id", "123"); as suggested, but then ?

Comment: So `t` is your inserted element, do with it what ever you want

Comment: Why do you need a reference to the inserted element? When do you want to do what to it?